# Program path uses differently cased character as file on disk; this might result in breakpoints not being hit

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have recently started to study JavaScript. I've installed Node.js and I'm trying to code using Visual Studio on macOS Catalina. 
I've a problem about the VSCode debugger.
It shows me the message in the title when I run the program with or without debugger.

Here's the launch.json file that I'm using:

```
{

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [


    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${file}",

    }
]
}
```

I'm using

```
"program": "${file}"
```

because I want that when I press F5 or ^F5 the open file is executed.

Some idea on how to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was done to some accented char in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes also add the same problem, and my js file was located in a path where a folder had an accent (non-english speaking problem I think....), I removed the accent and it worked !